# Could not execute procedure on remote server via Linked server

Tags: sql-server-2014, ssrs-2014, ssrs-subscription

I triggered a subscription using following query on Server-A using following query and it executes correctly -

On Server-A:

```
EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='452e4a40-7442-4377-abe3-1b96fc953956'
```

However, when I trigger it from Server B by adding Server-A as a Linked Server, then it doesn't work. It fails by throwing below error -

On Server-B:

```
EXEC [Server-A].ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='452e4a40-7442-4377-abe3-1b96fc953956'
```

Error:

> Could not execute procedure on remote server 'Server-A' because SQL Server is not configured for remote access. Ask your system administrator to reconfigure SQL Server to allow remote access.

I have enabled the Remote Access configuration on Server-A by

```
USE ReportServer ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO
```

Still it gives me above mentioned error.

Can anyone help me on this? Thanks

**UPDATE**

NOT a single Stored Procedure is getting called via Linked Server. This has been  observed after latest patch installed on Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 1):

Despite being an old thread forget about enabling remote access (and restart service) on remote server and try:

```
EXEC (N'ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType=''TimedSubscription'', @EventData=''452e4a40-7442-4377-abe3-1b96fc953956'' ') AT [Server-A]
```